# Wix Toolset - ComponentGroupRef works with external project file?

Tags: wix

I have the following in my Product.wxs file.

```
<Feature Id="PA5gFeature" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" Title="$(var.ApplicationName)" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="PA5GSite.Content" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SiteBinaries" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ShortcutGroup" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ConfigApp" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="PA5GApp" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ConfigSupportDlls" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ConfigReports" />

  <ComponentRef Id="PersistWebSiteValues" />
  <!--<ComponentRef Id="ChangeLogFolder" />-->
  <ComponentRef Id="ConfigReportFolder" />
  <ComponentRef Id="PA5GRunFolder" />
</Feature>
```

When I search with PA5GSite.Content in the entire project, I do not find it at all. On the other hand I see a project file of an outside project as a shortcut inside the installer project, like below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

If I delete this project shortcut file from installer project and try to build, it gives me error: `error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixC
omponentGroup:PA5GSite.Content' in section 'Product:*'`

The reference is definitely correct and linked, but I do not understand how this is done. If i try to add reference in the Wix project to that outside project, it adds a reference in the reference folder but do not add shortcut file like before and it do not fix the error again. My question is, what is going on in here and how it works? How can I do something like this myself because I have to replace the current project file with a new project file. But I do not find any option in Wix to do that. Where should I look into?

Comment: It is very possible that the .csproj file has been edited to contain additional wix directives, or that the `WebConfigTransform.xslt` is doing something special. Can you take a look at those files and post any relevant code snippets?

Comment: I think I solved that mystery. I found the clue in the Wix Installer project file itself. I am adding the solution in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved that mystery. I found the clue in the Wix Installer project file itself. I unload the wix project and then edited it manually. There I found a Harvest block which references the csproj file and i replace that with new project file and it all worked in the same way when I reload the Wix project. I found the clue from Wix Cookbook where it mentioned about this.